# WCF goes offline automatically

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-8

I have hosted a WCF service application on IIS8 (Windows Server 2012 R2). These services automatically goes offline sometimes an the other applications which uses these services throw this error,

> The requested service, 'http://10.230.245.156:8086/Apis/ILQ/Services/ILQInfoService.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.

When I open the Web.config of the WCF application and save it again, the services starts working back again.

Comment: It sounds like the app pool is being shut down for some reason - possibly an error.  Did you look in the application event viewer to see if there were any errors logged there?

Comment: yes, I checked the event viewer. no errors have been logged. only warnings.